# makeClusterPSOCK ERROR workers failed to connect

Tags: r, debugging, error-handling, seurat

I encounter this error when running Seurat on R.

**Error in makeClusterPSOCK(workers, ...) :
Cluster setup failed. 4 of 4 workers failed to connect.**

Never happened before installing R 4.1.

I have tried to no avail

- parallel:::setDefaultClusterOptions(setup_strategy = "sequential")
- cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2, setup_strategy = "sequential")

Any suggestions (and maybe a little explanation because I am relatively new to R still)? My computer overheats and I believe the command below is not working

****options(future.globals.maxSize = 8000 * 1024^2)**

**plan("multiprocess", workers = 4)****

Answer (score 0):

4.1 R/RStudio has all sorts of issues with `parallel` right now. I experienced similar issues with the `CB2` package on R 4.1 which also uses `parallel` for multicore support. This is probably related to an as of yet unpatched bug in R 4.1 (mentioned [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6692) and [here](https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18119)), though there is now a specific fix in R-devel 80472. If your issues are unresolved with the advice from those threads, I suggest rolling back to a previous R version that doesn't present the issue.